# How to rename a date frame in a list as it is written in the first column of each list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a large list with more than 100 data frames in it. For simplification I show a list with three data frames ("dummy data). I would like to name each data frame as it is written in the first column. In my example I would like to rename `DF1` to `TGX`. The same for `DF2` to `TBF` and `DF3` to `TZW`.

```
# dummy data
listDF <- list(
  DF1 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TGX", "TGX", "TGX", "TGX"),
    RC = c(0, 1, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(0, 3, 4, 0),
    RC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3)
  ),
  DF2 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TBF", "TBF", "TBF", "TBF"),
    RC = c(2, 1, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(4, 3, 4, 0),
    RC.norm = c(1, 3, 3, 3),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 3, 3, 3)
  ),
  DF3 = data.frame(
    sample = c("TZW", "TZW", "TZW", "TZW"),
    RC = c(4, 3, 2, 3),
    medRC = c(1, 3, 2, 0),
    RC.norm = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
    medRC.norm = c(0, 7, 5, 3)
  )
)
```

```
    listDF 

    # $DF1
    #   sample  RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TGX    0     0       0          0
    # 2  TGX    1     3       3          3
    # 3  TGX    2     4       3          3
    # 4  TGX    3     0       3          3

    # $DF2
    #   sample RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TBF   2     4       1       0
    # 3  TBF   1     3       3       3 
    # 4  TBF   2     4       3       3
    # 5  TBF   3     0       3       3

    # $DF3
    #   sample  RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
    # 1  TZW    4     1       1          0
    # 2  TZW    3     3       1          7
    # 3  TZW    2     2       1          5
    # 4  TZW    3     0       1          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the first cell value from each dataframe and rename :

```
names(listDF) <- sapply(listDF, function(x) x[1, 1])

listDF
#$TGX
#  sample RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
#1    TGX  0     0       0          0
#2    TGX  1     3       3          3
#3    TGX  2     4       3          3
#4    TGX  3     0       3          3

#$TBF
#  sample RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
#1    TBF  2     4       1          0
#2    TBF  1     3       3          3
#3    TBF  2     4       3          3
#4    TBF  3     0       3          3

#$TZW
#  sample RC medRC RC.norm medRC.norm
#1    TZW  4     1       1          0
#2    TZW  3     3       1          7
#3    TZW  2     2       1          5
#4    TZW  3     0       1          3
```